# Append array to existing json file without loading and decoding the hole file

Tags: php, file, upload, import

I´m creating a txt file importer using php, wich can be quite large reaching about 150MB in the near future, what i´ve done is divide the import process in a few steps, and in one of them a save the data extracted from the txt to a new json file.
What i like to do is append a new json encoded array to this file in each loop, avoiding having a very big array after 80MB processed and save everything at once, can anyone tell me how insert a new json encoded array into a existing json file without loading the hole file, decode it insert to the array and encode it again ? this could save a lots of resources in my inporter, i´ve searched trough out the site, but did not find anything like this.

Comment: You should really use a database. Try sqlite if you want a "no-setup" solution

Comment: Would that be faster and less resource consuming ? I did it by saving a json file thinking it would be that.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using a database for this, as One Trick Pony said.  SQLite is a good option if you don't want to mess around with configuration.  In saying that, I see one other way this could be achieved.  Provided your installation of PHP can run `shell_exec`, and the structure you want to modify isn't deeply nested, e.g. adding top level keys to something like

```
{
   "key0": {
             "value": { ... }
             "value": { ... }
           }
   "key1": { ... }
}
```

then you can use shell exec to remove the last line (`}`) of the `.json` file with

```
shell_exec('sed $d /path/to/file.json');
```

then store your next key in a variable as raw JSON without the opening curly brace (but retain closing):

```
$json = <<<EOT
"key2": {
          "value": {...}
        }
}
EOT;
```

and append this to the end of your JSON file:

```
shell_exec("$json >> /path/to/file.json");
```

If you're really optimising resources you should not use `EOT` and input it as a flat string, this goes for your whole file: those newline characters have to be stored.

However all of this is an extremely hacky solution and you should use a database if at all possible.  Opening an SQLite database causes the whole thing to be loaded into memory, so may not help you from a resource consumption standpoint.

Hardware is cheap, search around and I'm sure you'll find some hosting that can handle this job and not break your budget - you can get dedicated servers for less than £10 a month these days, or you could spin up an Amazon EC2 instance just to run this job every now and again, dump it back to your server (or S3), and spin down.  It would cost almost nothing.

There will come a time when your database is so big that SQLite is an inefficient solution (because the whole thing is loaded into memory), in which case you should go for a proper DB like MySQL/PostgreSQL/... which can handle huge databases on comparatively limited resources.